# Efficient sse shuffle mask generation for left-packing byte elements

Tags: performance, x86, sse, shuffle, simd

What would be an efficient way to optimize the following code with sse ?

```
uint16_t change1= ... ;
uint8_t* pSrc   = ... ;
uint8_t* pDest  = ... ;

if(change1 & 0x0001) *pDest++ = pSrc[0];
if(change1 & 0x0002) *pDest++ = pSrc[1];
if(change1 & 0x0004) *pDest++ = pSrc[2];
if(change1 & 0x0008) *pDest++ = pSrc[3];

if(change1 & 0x0010) *pDest++ = pSrc[4];
if(change1 & 0x0020) *pDest++ = pSrc[5];
if(change1 & 0x0040) *pDest++ = pSrc[6];
if(change1 & 0x0080) *pDest++ = pSrc[7];

if(change1 & 0x0100) *pDest++ = pSrc[8];
if(change1 & 0x0200) *pDest++ = pSrc[9];
if(change1 & 0x0400) *pDest++ = pSrc[10];
if(change1 & 0x0800) *pDest++ = pSrc[11];

if(change1 & 0x1000) *pDest++ = pSrc[12];
if(change1 & 0x2000) *pDest++ = pSrc[13];
if(change1 & 0x4000) *pDest++ = pSrc[14];
if(change1 & 0x8000) *pDest++ = pSrc[15];
```

So far I am using a quite big lookup table for it, but I really want to get rid of it:

```
SSE3Shuffle::Entry& e0 = SSE3Shuffle::g_Shuffle.m_Entries[change1];
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)pDest, _mm_shuffle_epi8(*(__m128i*)pSrc, e0.mask));
pDest += e0.offset;
```

Comment: Are there any constraints at all on the contents of `change1` or can it be any possible 16 bit pattern ?

Comment: all bits are used, all bit combinations will appear.

Comment: With movemask && pext you could bit-slice all the bits from __m128i to 8 registers, but I don't know how to deinterleave those...

Comment: It is possible to do a compression like that [the same way that pext is emulated](https://godbolt.org/g/ge71mo) but that's horrible.

Comment: Related: [BMI2 mask-generation for AVX2 left-packing of 32-bit or 64-bit elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask).  Not directly applicable, because it doesn't easily handle smaller elements.

Comment: Similarly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959079) might be of interest to you. It shows how to generate a `_mm_shuffle_epi8` shuffle mask for 16x8 bit elements using the `pext` instruction. In your case you can leave out the ' `0xFF` at the unwanted positions' part. Although you might need the `popcnt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming:

```
change1 = _mm_movemask_epi8(bytemask);
offset = popcnt(change1);
```

On large buffers, using two shuffles and a 1 KiB table is only ~10% slower than using 1 shuffle and a 1MiB table. My attempts at generating the shuffle mask via prefix sums and bit twiddling are about about half the speed of the table based methods
(solutions using `pext/pdep` were not explored).

Reducing table size: Use two lookups into a 2 KiB table instead of 1 lookup into a 1 MiB table.  Always keep the top-most byte - if that byte is to be discarded then it doesn't matter what byte is at that position (down to 7-bit indices, or 1 KiB table). Further reduce possible combinations by manually packing the two bytes in each 16-bit lane (down to a 216 byte table).

The following example strips whitespace from text using `SSE4.1`. If only `SSSE3` is available then `blendv` can be emulated. The 64-bit halves are re-combined by overlapping writes to memory, but they could be re-combined in the `xmm` register (as seen in the `AVX2` example).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <smmintrin.h> // SSE4.1

size_t despacer (void* dst_void, void* src_void, size_t length)
{
    uint8_t* src = (uint8_t*)src_void;
    uint8_t* dst = (uint8_t*)dst_void;

    if (length >= 16) {
        // table of control characters (space, tab, newline, carriage return)
        const __m128i lut_cntrl = _mm_setr_epi8(' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '\t', '\n', 0, 0, '\r', 0, 0);

        // bits[4:0] = index -> ((trit_d * 0) + (trit_c * 9) + (trit_b * 3) + (trit_a * 1))
        // bits[15:7] = popcnt
        const __m128i sadmask = _mm_set1_epi64x(0x8080898983838181);

        // adding 8 to each shuffle index is cheaper than extracting the high qword
        const __m128i offset = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(0x0808080808080808);

        // shuffle control indices
        static const uint64_t table[27] = {
            0x0000000000000706, 0x0000000000070600, 0x0000000007060100, 0x0000000000070602,
            0x0000000007060200, 0x0000000706020100, 0x0000000007060302, 0x0000000706030200,
            0x0000070603020100, 0x0000000000070604, 0x0000000007060400, 0x0000000706040100,
            0x0000000007060402, 0x0000000706040200, 0x0000070604020100, 0x0000000706040302,
            0x0000070604030200, 0x0007060403020100, 0x0000000007060504, 0x0000000706050400,
            0x0000070605040100, 0x0000000706050402, 0x0000070605040200, 0x0007060504020100,
            0x0000070605040302, 0x0007060504030200, 0x0706050403020100
        };

        const uint8_t* end = &src[length & ~15];
        do {
            __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)src);
            src += 16;

            // detect spaces
            __m128i mask = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_shuffle_epi8(lut_cntrl, v), v);

            // shift w/blend: each word now only has 3 states instead of 4
            // which reduces the possiblities per qword from 128 to 27
            v = _mm_blendv_epi8(v, _mm_srli_epi16(v, 8), mask);

            // extract bitfields describing each qword: index, popcnt
            __m128i desc = _mm_sad_epu8(_mm_and_si128(mask, sadmask), sadmask);
            size_t lo_desc = (size_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(desc);
            size_t hi_desc = (size_t)_mm_extract_epi16(desc, 4);

            // load shuffle control indices from pre-computed table
            __m128i lo_shuf = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)&table[lo_desc & 0x1F]);
            __m128i hi_shuf = _mm_or_si128(_mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)&table[hi_desc & 0x1F]), offset);

            // store an entire qword then advance the pointer by how ever
            // many of those bytes are actually wanted. Any trailing
            // garbage will be overwritten by the next store.
            // note: little endian byte memory order
            _mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)dst, _mm_shuffle_epi8(v, lo_shuf));
            dst += (lo_desc >> 7);
            _mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)dst, _mm_shuffle_epi8(v, hi_shuf));
            dst += (hi_desc >> 7);
        } while (src != end);
    }

    // tail loop
    length &= 15;
    if (length != 0) {
        const uint64_t bitmap = 0xFFFFFFFEFFFFC1FF;
        do {
            uint64_t c = *src++;
            *dst = (uint8_t)c;
            dst += ((bitmap >> c) & 1) | ((c + 0xC0) >> 8);
        } while (--length);
    }

    // return pointer to the location after the last element in dst
    return (size_t)(dst - ((uint8_t*)dst_void));
}
```

Whether the tail loop should be vectorized or use `cmov` is left as an exercise for the reader. Writing each byte unconditionally/branchlessly is fast when the input is unpredictable.

---

Using `AVX2` to generate the shuffle control mask using an in-register table is only slightly slower than using large precomputed tables.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

// probably needs improvment...
size_t despace_avx2_vpermd(const char* src_void, char* dst_void, size_t length)
{
    uint8_t* src = (uint8_t*)src_void;
    uint8_t* dst = (uint8_t*)dst_void;

    const __m256i lut_cntrl2    = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_setr_epi8(' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '\t', '\n', 0, 0, '\r', 0, 0));
    const __m256i permutation_mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x( 0x0020100884828180 );
    const __m256i invert_mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x( 0x0020100880808080 ); 
    const __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    const __m256i fixup = _mm256_set_epi32(
        0x08080808, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00000000, 0x07070707,
        0x08080808, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00000000, 0x07070707
    );
    const __m256i lut = _mm256_set_epi32(
        0x04050607, // 0x03020100', 0x000000'07
        0x04050704, // 0x030200'00, 0x0000'0704
        0x04060705, // 0x030100'00, 0x0000'0705
        0x04070504, // 0x0300'0000, 0x00'070504
        0x05060706, // 0x020100'00, 0x0000'0706
        0x05070604, // 0x0200'0000, 0x00'070604
        0x06070605, // 0x0100'0000, 0x00'070605
        0x07060504  // 0x00'000000, 0x'07060504
    );

    // hi bits are ignored by pshufb, used to reject movement of low qword bytes
    const __m256i shuffle_a = _mm256_set_epi8(
        0x7F, 0x7E, 0x7D, 0x7C, 0x7B, 0x7A, 0x79, 0x78, 0x07, 0x16, 0x25, 0x34, 0x43, 0x52, 0x61, 0x70,
        0x7F, 0x7E, 0x7D, 0x7C, 0x7B, 0x7A, 0x79, 0x78, 0x07, 0x16, 0x25, 0x34, 0x43, 0x52, 0x61, 0x70
    );

    // broadcast 0x08 then blendd...
    const __m256i shuffle_b = _mm256_set_epi32(
        0x08080808, 0x08080808, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x08080808, 0x08080808, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
    );

    for( uint8_t* end = &src[(length & ~31)]; src != end; src += 32){
        __m256i r0,r1,r2,r3,r4;
        unsigned int s0,s1;

        r0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *)src); // asrc

        // detect spaces
        r1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(_mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut_cntrl2, r0), r0);

        r2 = _mm256_sad_epu8(zero, r1);
        s0 = (unsigned)_mm256_movemask_epi8(r1);
        r1 = _mm256_andnot_si256(r1, permutation_mask);

        r1 = _mm256_sad_epu8(r1, invert_mask); // index_bitmap[0:5], low32_spaces_count[7:15]

        r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(r2, zero);

        r2 = _mm256_sub_epi8(shuffle_a, r2); // add space cnt of low qword
        s0 = ~s0;

        r3 = _mm256_slli_epi64(r1, 29); // move top part of index_bitmap to high dword
        r4 = _mm256_srli_epi64(r1, 7); // number of spaces in low dword 

        r4 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(r4, shuffle_b);
        r1 = _mm256_or_si256(r1, r3);

        r1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(lut, r1);
        s1 = _mm_popcnt_u32(s0);
        r4 = _mm256_add_epi8(r4, shuffle_a);
        s0 = s0 & 0xFFFF; // isolate low oword

        r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(r4, r2);
        s0 = _mm_popcnt_u32(s0);

        r2 = _mm256_max_epu8(r2, r4); // pin low qword bytes

        r1 = _mm256_xor_si256(r1, fixup);

        r1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(r1, r2); // complete shuffle mask

        r0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(r0, r1); // despace!

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)dst, _mm256_castsi256_si128(r0));
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dst[s0], _mm256_extracti128_si256(r0,1));
        dst += s1;
    }
    // tail loop
    length &= 31;
    if (length != 0) {
        const uint64_t bitmap = 0xFFFFFFFEFFFFC1FF;
        do {
            uint64_t c = *src++;
            *dst = (uint8_t)c;
            dst += ((bitmap >> c) & 1) | ((c + 0xC0) >> 8);
        } while (--length);
    }
    return (size_t)(dst - ((uint8_t*)dst_void));
}
```

---

For posterity, the 1 KiB version (generating the table is left as an exercise for the reader).

```
static const uint64_t table[128] __attribute__((aligned(64))) = {
    0x0706050403020100, 0x0007060504030201, ..., 0x0605040302010700, 0x0605040302010007 
};
const __m128i mask_01 = _mm_set1_epi8( 0x01 );

__m128i vector0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)src);
__m128i vector1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32( vector0, 0x0E );

__m128i bytemask0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi8( ???, vector0); // detect bytes to omit

uint32_t bitmask0 = _mm_movemask_epi8(bytemask0) & 0x7F7F;
__m128i hsum = _mm_sad_epu8(_mm_add_epi8(bytemask0, mask_01), _mm_setzero_si128());

vector0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector0, _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*) &table[(uint8_t)bitmask0]));
_mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)dst, vector0);
dst += (uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(hsum);

vector1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector1, _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*) &table[bitmask0 >> 8]));
_mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)dst, vector1);
dst += (uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(hsum, hsum));
```

---

https://github.com/InstLatx64/AVX512_VPCOMPRESSB_Emu has some benchmarks.

Comment: In the table version, it would probably be cheaper to do `dst += _popcnt32(bitmask0 & 0xFF)`, since the compiler already needs the two bytes of the bitmask in separate integer registers (to use as array indices).

Comment: Or you could SAD against something other than `setzero` to avoid the `add` to swap from 0/-1 to 1/0.  `counts = sad(bytemask, set1_epi8(0x80))` would add 128 where the mask was 0, or 127 where the mask was -1.  So for each 64b half of `counts`, it's just `popcount = counts - 127*8`.  This can still compile to `psadbw xmm0, xmm7` / `movq eax, xmm0` / `movq xmm1, [table + rax*8 - 127*8*8]`, so the offset is taken care of for free as part of the addressing mode.  (Not even costing any code-size in non-PIC code where `static const table` was already a disp32 rather than a register).

Comment: This reminds me: `_mm_cvtsi128_si64(hsum);` could be `_mm_cvtsi128_si32(hsum);`, because you know your psadbw result is all zeros outside the low byte.  This avoids a REX prefix (if your compiler doesn't spot the optimization itself), and lets the same code work in 32-bit mode in case that's relevant.

Comment: Instead of `vector1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(vector0, vector0);` to set up the high half of your vector for a `pshufb`, you could offset the shuffle indices instead.  `_mm_add_epi8( load(table[(bitmask0 >> 8) & 0x7F]),  set1_epi8(8))`.  This would take an extra constant, but reduce pressure on the shuffle port.  (`paddb` can run on more ports than `punpckhqdq`)

Comment: @PeterCordes - `_mm_or_si128(load64(table[..]), set1_epi8(8))` was slower on my Nehalem, not sure why, seems like it should be faster.
`movq` is faster for 64-bit builds, `movd` for 32-bit builds
`popcnt` requires (in practice) sse4.2.

the population count is not currently used for indexing into the table, would it be beneficially to do so?

Comment: Oh, good point, I guess `popcnt` would bump up the requirement from SSSE3 to SSE4.2/popcnt for the 128b version.  I don't think you can use `popcnt` as part of the table indexing; I meant that it might be faster to `popcnt` the values you used for table indexing and remove the `_mm_sad` / `movd` stuff.

Comment: *slower on my Nehalem*: Perhaps a register-read stall from having an extra constant register.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  If `movq` is faster in your 64-bit builds, is that because your compiler is wasting an instruction zero-extending the result after?  Or maybe it's a Nehalem decode / alignment issue.

Comment: I put your code from git up on godbolt (https://godbolt.org/g/33kobf) to see gcc/clang output.  Yeah, `_mm_cvtsi128_si32`'s return value is `int`, so unless you cast it to `(unsigned)`, compilers insert a `movsx` instruction :P.  But with a cast, you do get the smaller code-size for free.  Other stuff: clang optimizes the `vector1=unpackhi()` to a `pshufd` to save a `movdqa` instruction.  Compilers mask the two bytes of `bitmask0` separately.  Use `bitmask0 &= 0x7F7F` to let them use one AND and two MOVZX instructions (or AND+MOVZX+SHR, if they don't want to `movzx ecx, dh`).

Comment: Also looks like clang's loop could save an integer instruction by using an end-pointer as the loop bound, since it's not using the loop-counter (`rdx`) as an index.  gcc does that transformation for you.

Answer (score 2):

If one is willing to use BMI2 available on haswell and later, one can use `pdep` to first compress unwanted nibbles out from uint64_t, and then use `pext` to scatter the result to shuffle mask.

```
// Step 1 -- replicate mask to nibbles
uint64_t change4 = pdep(change1, 0x1111111111111111ULL) * 0x0F;
// Step 2 -- extract index from array of nibbles
uint64_t indices = pext(0xfedcba09876543210, change4);
// Step 3 -- interleave nibbles to octects
uint64_t high = pdep(indices >> 32ULL,0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F);
uint64_t low = pdep(indices, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
// Step 4 -- use these two masks to compress pSrc
__m128i compressed = _mm_shuffle_epi8(pSrc, _mm_set_epi64(high, low));
// Step 5 -- store 16 bytes unaligned
_mm_storeu_si128(pDst, compressed);
// Step 6 -- increment target pointer
pDst += __mm_popcnt(change1);
```

Also other variants (based on cumulative sum or sorting the 'X's (or zero bits) out from XX23456789abXXef will first require some technique to spread the bits from uint16_t evenly to __m128i (i.e. reverse of movemask_epi8).

The 64k entry LUT can however be split to top and bottom parts:

```
int c = change1 & 0xff;
int p = __popcount(c);
uint64_t a = LUT256[c];               // low part of index
uint64_t b = LUT256[change1 >> 8];    // top part of index
b += addlut9[p];                      // 0x0101010101010101 * p
// Then must concatenate b|a at pth position of 'a'
if (p < 8)
{
   a |= b << (8*(8-p));
   b >>= 8*p;
}
__m128i d = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128(pSrc),_mm_set1_epi64(b,a));
// and continue with steps 5 and 6 as before
```

Comment: Infact, breaking the bit LUT down into 2 small ones is the solution. The big LUT is destroying the cache, while 2 small ones work nicely.