# AVX2 delete special byte and bring the next bytes 1 unit back

Tags: c, assembly, simd, avx2

I have this bytes in my YMM register (32-BYTE)

```
47 105 110 100 101 120 46 112 -1 104 112 -1 63 107 101 121 -1 49 61 118 97 108 117 101 49 38 107 101 121 50 61 118
```

There are three -1 bytes in this YMM register. I want to delete all -1 bytes and shift the next bytes 1 unit back to be something like this

```
47 105 110 100 101 120 46 112 104 112 63 107 101 121 49 61 118 97 108 117 101 49 38 107 101 121 50 61 118 0 0 0
```

I just want to delete all -1 and bring the next bytes 1 unit back ...

Is there any instruction for this action? How can i do this?

I can handle both C or assembly suggestion ....

Thank you.

Comment: Left-packing with byte granularity in a YMM register is very hard with AVX2 (and isn't much better with AVX512).  Can you work in smaller chunks over a larger array or do you really need this for single YMM vectors?  (Note that left-packing dwords efficiently is possible: [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240))

Comment: Oh, but [Efficient sse shuffle mask generation for left-packing byte elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45506309) does have an AVX2 byte pack version using very different tricks.  It produces four possibly-overlapping chunks of output, not a single vector result, though, because lane-crossing and element-crossing is hard.

Comment: Ok thank you .. Im reading those posts ....